# Can I make scope extend an object in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Say I write an app like this:

```
<script>

myArray=<?php echo $array;?>;
app={
    myArray:myArray,
    myIndex:myArray.length-1,
    back:function(){this.myIndex--;console.log("You clicked back");},
    forward:function(){this.myIndex++}
}
</script>
```

Now I want to add a UI so I decide to use angularJS. So I write this:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="value in myArray | slice:myIndex:myIndex+1">
            <div ng-cick="back()">Back</div>
            <div ng-bind="value"></div>
            <div ng-cick="forward()">Forward</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also I got this

```
var myApp=angular.module('myApp', [])

myApp.filter('slice', function() {
  return function(arr, start, end) {
    return arr.slice(start, end);
  };
});

myApp.controller("AppCtrl",function($scope){
    $.extend($scope,app);
})
```

Then I click the back button, and the console logs "You clicked back", but the value does not change. Why doesn't JQuery extend work in this situation and how can I get this to work correctly?

Comment: `$.extend` will work fine.. But... read/watch [this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes).

Comment: Why?!? Why do you stab our eyes by removing the spaces from your code?

http://static4.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20120328010203/adventuretimewithfinnandjake/images/b/b2/My_eyes.gif

Comment: What are you talking about @hypno7oad?

Comment: back:function(){this.myIndex--;console.log("You clicked back");},

There's no spaces in that code. It's much more readable if it was something like...

    back: function () {
        this.myIndex--;
        console.log("You clicked back");
    },

ugh... I can't format in the comments. :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$.extend` will work fine.. But.. You don't really need it.. read/watch [this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes).

To fix your problem... just do this:

```
  myApp.controller("AppCtrl",function($scope){
      $scope.app = app;
  })
```

and.

```
  <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="value in app.myArray | slice:app.myIndex:app.myIndex+1">
        <button ng-click="app.back()">Back</button>
        <div>{{value}}</div>
        <button ng-click="app.forward()">Forward</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Hope that points you in the right direction.

**update**

One solution would be to use the controller as syntax... so

```
myApp.controller("AppCtrl",function(){
    angular.extend(this,app);
})
```

and

```
  <div ng-controller="AppCtrl as app">
    <div ng-repeat="value in app.myArray | slice:app.myIndex:app.myIndex+1">
        <button ng-click="app.back()">Back</button>
        <div ng-bind="value"></div>
        <button ng-click="app.forward()">Forward</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

In the first example `$scope.app` has context (because its the owner of forward,back etc that you mixed in).

Comment: Thanks but I don't think it's this simple. The problem is that my functions use the keyword `this` which I'm realizing doesnt refer to the scope once I extend it...it is unpredictable to me what `this` will refer to...it appears to refer to the controller when I test with console.log